# apply homography matrix to a set of points in matlab

Tags: matlab, homography

I have calculated homography matrix using these set of points

trapezium points are

```
x=[ 102,48; 206,48; 257,143; 53,118]
```

square points(projected points) are                                    `y=[0,0; 335,0; 335,178; 0,178]`

Homography matrix

```
H=                                                                
  -0.0000   -0.0173   -0.0001                                       
   0.0000    0.0382    0.0001                                      
  -0.0000   -0.9990    0.0126
```

Now , I want to apply H to x to get projected points (y)

How can I calculate that in matlab ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual way of doing this:

```
% your vectors and your H
x = [ 102,48; 206,48; 257,143; 53,118];
y = [0,0; 335,0; 335,178; 0,178];
H = [-0.0000   -0.0173   -0.0001;                                       
   0.0000    0.0382    0.0001;                                    
  -0.0000   -0.9990    0.0126];

x = [x ones(4,1)]; % make your coords homogenous
y = [y ones(4,1)];

x_projected = H*x';
x_projected = x_projected./repmat(x_projected(3,:),3,1); % normalize
```

`x_projected` is 3x4 in this case and every column is one of the projected points.

To check the projection vs. your y: euclidean distance of columns of `y'-x_projected` should be small depending on your H.

Comment: it's coming like this                                                                                       
  x_projected =

    0.0174    0.0174    0.0174    0.0174
   -0.0382   -0.0382   -0.0382   -0.0382
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000                                                                                      I should get back my projected points i.e the square points.... But it is not coming               How to solve this problem?

Comment: @S.D.G:If the error between the projection and your y is big, it means that your H is probably incorrect. How did you determine it?